# Ehcache intrigation with Spring project

Tags: spring, jdbc, ehcache

i am facing this error:-

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache]
>   Offending resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml]

If any solution for this give me suggestion.

Comment: Please post your application-context.xml file and maven dependencies if you use maven .

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a library issue . Check if you have the ehcache jar in your classpath . Else download it from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/) .